# Laravel I cannot get into Controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

The `storeClientRequest` Cannot be triggered, is there any mistake here ? When I hit submit, the page shows `404 Not found`

Form

```
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" action="store-client-request/{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
    @csrf
        //////content
  </form>
```

Route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'user', 'middleware'=>['isUser','auth']], function(){

    Route::post('store-client-request/{user}', [UserController::class, 'storeClientRequest']);
});
```

Controller

```
function storeClientRequest(User $user)
{
    dd('hi');
    return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Create request successfully");
}
```

Comment: As the route is in a group - have you tried `/user/store-client-request/...`

Comment: I would also advise you to name your routes, and use the `route()` helper instead of the static form action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a name to your route :

   ```
   Route::post('store-client-request/{user}', [UserController::class, 'storeClientRequest'])->name("store.client.request");
   ```
2. Make sure you run

   ```
   php artisan optimize
   ```
3. Reference your route by name in the opening form tag :

   ```
   action="{{ route('store.client.request', ['user' => Auth::user()->id]) }}">
   ```

That way, it doesn't matter (a) what the route prefix is (that it looks like you've forgotten to include) or (b) if the address to the route changes later down the line - the {{ route() }} blade directive will always pull in the correct URL, along with the relevant parameters.

Comment: Yes! This is the best option. This way the url changes if the route config changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I see through you code: your full route is /user/store-client-request/{user}

Therefore in you action you should put

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" action="/user/store-client-request/{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
@csrf
    //////content
```

Comment: This will solve the problem, but is not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

In your Route there is         /user/store-client-request/{user}

So Add this in your Action

```
   <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" action="/user/store-client-request/{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

  </form>
```